# Gravity Forms minDate not disabling past dates

Tags: javascript, php, filter, datepicker, gravityforms

I’m trying to disable past dates from the datepicker in Gravity Forms, and I keep getting console errors or it's just not working...

I first tried:

```
gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
      if ( formId == 2 && fieldId == 111 ) {
          optionsObj.minDate = 0;
      }
      return optionsObj;
  });
```

and I got this error: `gform is not defined`

And then I tried defining gform with:

`var gform = $('#gform_2');` and `var gform = document.getElementById('gform_2');`

And got this error: `gform.addFilter is not a function`

Wrapping it in `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { });` doesn't give me errors, but it also doesn't disable past dates.

I even went the old school route and tried:

```
$("#input_2_111").datepicker( { 
    minDate: "+0d"  });
```

And that didn’t work… I see the PHP `gform_date_min_year` hook but nothing for a min date. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try using our free Gravity Forms Custom Javascript plugin. It handles loading snippets like this at the appropriate time.

http://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-custom-javascript/

If you want to make things even easier, use [Gravity Forms Limit Dates](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-limit-dates/) and configure this right from the field settings.

Comment: Thanks! Added the custom JS plugin and put the JS in there... and it's still not working  Not getting any errors either.

Comment: Never mind. I finally just figured out why. I had conflicting code. Either way, thanks for your help!